# I am where you are now, too

Tags: word

I can lead to a deduction.

Or I may request one.

Two of me are mediocre.

I can be your beloved one.

What am I?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What am I? You are just

> **so**

I can lead to a deduction.

> So - therefore.

Or I may request one.

> So? - asking for a reply.

Two of me are mediocre.

> so-so - not great, ok.

I can be your beloved one.

> SO - significant other.

Title: I am where you are now, too

> Stack Overflow

Comment: Well, technically you are not at that exact place now. It's a sibling? Child? But not the same thing.